# How do I wall off Origin? I received a gift but this app is not trusted

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition, origin

Time to see if anything has changed but not risk my privacy at the same time. I was dismayed to see other responses to similar requests to manage origin app focused on instructions to uninstall if you don’t like it or ‘it is not spyware’. I have not willfully bought an EA game in protest for almost 10 years.

My request is how to setup a walled garden to prevent EA or Origin from having access to my data and in turn violate my privacy. I will address the reason for this concern to be valid and then the technical request.

I wish to create a ‘walled garden’ on my PC to prevent any privacy busting behavior by this app.

This garden request would be useful for any such app that has security concerns or a questionable history.

Comment: Easiest way is a separate computer to play this game. But seriously, if you don't like the EULA, don't play the game. If enough people do so, they will change their habits. (and please cut down on the rant)

Comment: I appreciate the reply. I’m at the 10 year mark so voting with my wallet did not work. And they did not change their behavior. The only one put out is me in missing all the games my friends play and the IP I enjoy. So I think a walled garden is a good middle ground. 

Perhaps a VM?

Comment: This question might be better suited for the SuperUsers stack exchange page or perhaps the CyberSecurity page, generalized to "How do I wall off an untrusted program or app while still being able to use it?"

Comment: I can certainly remove the fluff or rant as suggested and repost to SuperUsers. I really appreciate the title suggestion. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Couldn't you run it on a VM, like virtualbox?

Comment: This is far from perfect, but Kaspersky has a guide: https://www.kaspersky.co.uk/blog/origin-privacy-security/21790/

Comment: Thank you both. I’m barking up the VM tree right now. Thanks for the link!